# A bit curious about `mysql -e` output format with & without redirect

Tags: mysql, command-line, stdout

Say when I run `mysql -u user -p -e 'select id from db.users limit 1'`, I got:

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 8434 |
+------+
```

When I redirect the output/stdout to some file, like `mysql -u user -p -e 'select id from db.users limit 1' > /tmp/a.txt`, then I `cat /tmp/a.txt`, I got:

```
id
8434
```

So where do those little format strings go? Does it mean that `mysql` knows when it is redirected, so it returns a different format? I always thought a redirect(`>`) doesn't concern the previous command, that it doesn't have to know if or where its output is redirected. Or is it another explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get same output by adding `-B` option

```
    mysql -B -u user -p -e 'select id from db.users limit 1'
```

then you'll see

```
 id       
 8434
```

Also, `mysql` command tests if the cout is tty or not, to switch output formatting.
As you can see in the [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.6/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L1223) of `mysql` command.

Comment: `-B` means printing results using tab as the column separator, so it means the output of `mysql -e 'blahblah'` is separated by tab and new line, instead those '|' and '+' and '-'. Anyway, my question is, why the output format is different with & without a redirect. Does this mean `mysql` knows when its output is redirected to somewhere else?

Comment: @DeanWinchester "Does this mean mysql knows when its output is redirected to somewhere else" -> yes, mysql knows. I've edited the answer.

Comment: You're right:). `isatty` can test it, it's just about file descriptors. If there's a redirected, or a pipe, then the file descriptor is not 1 anymore. And I edited you answer a bit, something about `-B` is incorrect

Comment: @DeanWinchester Thanks for the suggestion! it seems that your suggestion was rejected by 3 other users, then I've updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same fancy table format when redirecting, add the `-t` flag or `--table` to your mysql command.

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Quincy |
+----+--------+
```

As for your question, mysql uses [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) under the hood to know if you are redirecting output.