# How to detect whether the command output is being used in unix pipe

Tags: mysql, unix, command, pipe, output

In MySql -e option prints different formatting when used the output with pipe.

Without Pipe

```
[root@localhost commands]# $MYSQL_CONNECT_STR -e 'select 0/8'
+--------+
| 0/8    |
+--------+
| 0.0000 |
+--------+
```

With Pipe -- no formatting.

```
[root@localhost commands]# $MYSQL_CONNECT_STR -e 'select 0/8'| more
0/8
0.0000
```

How the mysql command detecting that the output is going to fed to another command through pipe ?

Comment: Got Answers from 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812190/a-bit-curious-about-mysql-e-output-format-with-without-redirect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517250/how-do-i-detect-if-stdout-is-connected-to-a-tty-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system call to determine the characteristics of a file handle:

```
int fstat (int fd, struct stat *buf);

       struct stat {
           dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
           ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
           mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
           nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
           uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
           gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
           dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
           off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
           blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
           blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
           time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
           time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
           time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
       };
```

By inspecting the st_mode bits, the program can determine what type of device it is connected to.  See `man 2 fstat` for the full details.  In particular, there are macros which are meant to be system independent to distinguish between regular files, pipes, sockets, etc.

There is another system call which determines whether a file connection is to a terminal:

```
int isatty(int fd);
```

> DESCRIPTION
>         The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>         isatty() returns 1 if fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal; otherwise 0 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

It checks for tty

Check below links for more information

[A bit curious about `mysql -e` output format with & without redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812190/a-bit-curious-about-mysql-e-output-format-with-without-redirect)

[How do I detect if stdout is connected to a tty in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517250/how-do-i-detect-if-stdout-is-connected-to-a-tty-in-perl)